# Does zsh have an equivalent to bash's "history -c"?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, history

I'm administrating a linux server of a club, but I'm not the only admin. All admins log in as root. Please don't ask me why, it was the majority decision of the other admins. I know that this is not optimal.

However, I want to have my individual history when I login. With bash, I did it this way:

`history -c; history -r ~/.my_own_bash_history`

Now, we plan to switch to zsh. I'm not opposed to it, but testing zsh on my home PC, I miss the `history -c` functionality. I've learned that zsh has the `fc` command (instead of `history`) with `-R` and `-W` (instead of `-r` and `-w`) for reading/writing the history from/to a file. But I could not find anything like `-c` that clears the history completely, or an alternative that reads the history from a file in something like a *"replace all"* mode. Did I just overlook it or is it really missing ?

Comment: We often have shared development boards where most people log in as root. The first thing I always do is create my own login user, with its own home, history, shell scripts etc, and setup passwordless sudo for it. This is automated in a script, and so it is trivial to run on a new board, and is so vital to me I'll spend time updating the script for, say, a new OS we have to support.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on Unix & Linux:

> To get an empty history, temporarily set
>   [`HISTSIZE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTSIZE)
>   to zero.
>
> ```
> function erase_history { local HISTSIZE=0; }
> erase_history
> ```
>
> If you want to erase the new history from this shell instance but keep
>   the old history that was loaded initially, empty the history as above
>   then reload the saved history `fc -R` afterwards.
>
> If you don't want the `erase_history` call to be recorded in the
>   history, you can filter it out in the [`zshaddhistory`
>   hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-zshaddhistory).
>
> ```
> function zshaddhistory_erase_history {
>   [[ $1 != > [[:space:]]#erase_history[[:space:]]# ]] 
> }
> zshaddhistory_functions+=(zshaddhistory_erase_history)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Deleting one specific history element (`history -d
>   NUM` in bash) is another matter. I don't think there's
>   a way other than:
>
> 1. Save the history: `fc -AI` to append to the history file, or `fc -WI` to overwrite the history file, depending on your history sharing preferences.
> 2. Edit the history file (`$HISTFILE`).
> 3. Reload the history file: `fc -R`.

Source [How to clear history in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544815), answer by [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles-so-stop-being-evil)

Comment: I just tested it, and it works **almost** as desired. The history is empty afterwards, but the numbering of subsequent commands starts at the length of the old history + 1 instead of 1

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to fix that.